# how to run c# Form application inside c++/MFC application window

Tags: c#, dll, mfc, com, activex

I have a c# application and a C++/MFC application. The MFC application is build by other people I have build a c# part. Now I want to run the c# application as a part of c++ application.

What I have found is we can use dll (com,activeX) etc to communicate between two program . I am successful in passing the datas between two program using COM but how do I show entire "WINDOW FORM" inside vc++ application.

Is there a way to do this?
Is it  possible or we can just transfer data and get response to that data. Can we run entire exe or some other format of .net application into vc++ application ?

I also heard that we can do a command line execute method(using exec) to do communication between two program.(But I dont know how to do this and whether it works or not .)

[Note : I do not just want to run/call c# exe in c++ and run it but rather run c# application as a part of c++  ]

If there is a way to do this?  it would be very helpfull if someone could suggest me some way.

Comment: Since this is the same question [you asked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37154579/1889329) a day ago, it would be more appropriate to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37154579/edit) your previous question instead of posting a new one.

Comment: @IInspectable : I did this because I need some answer.Please help me if you have any suggestion.